# Enforcing Secure Connections for Bluetooth Keyboards

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to pair my keyboard (Keychron K10 Pro) to my computer with Secure Connection enabled, but it appears to be using "Secure Simple Pairing" instead. [I saw this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260101/bluez-le-secure-pairing-using-elliptical-curve-diffie-hellman-from-command-line) that mentioned `btmon` would indicate if pairing was done with Secure Simple Pairing or Secure connections, and in my case it appears to be using SSP. Furthermore, after pairing running `bluetoothctl info <dev>` does not list Secure Connection.

I have tried this on two different computers, one with a 4.2 Bluetooth adapter, the other with a 5.1 Bluetooth adapter.

Is there anyway to force the system to only allow Secure Connection?